# IBM Bluemix Db2 on Cloud "Error 401: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 401"

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

There is a problem opening the DB2 on Cloud from the catalog page.  When I click open I get an error page that says just 
"Error 401: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 401"

I am trying to load data into a table but can't do so from the command line either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to open a support ticket(https://watson.service-now.com/wcp) with them and provide more information in the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean after click on Open Console, then try to edit your error page URL and remove suffix (let there hostname only). Then provide username and password of your Db2 user.